# Live Server not works correctly (VSC) on Mac OS Ventura after something happened that I don't know

Tags: visual-studio-code, safari, preview, liveserver

I noticed that since some weeks VSC and Live Server don't work and I don't know.  On internet my domain works correctly, I tried also to create another User with Admin permissions and this time worked but I want that VSC and Live Server work correctly (naturally on Safari) as before on my personal User Account without have to change each time. I took some screenshots to show you what happening.

[Screenshot on website online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrvrf.png)
[Screenshot on local with Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vfp7.png)

I want to to tell also this: If I try to click on file from directory and "Open with..." (Safari) it show always the same problem.

I tried to use another app as Brackets but when I launch "Live Preview" the problem there is still. I tried to do Secure Reboot on Mac and reboot but nothing. I also tried to uninstall e reinstall again VSC and Live Server but the problem is always the same.